# Convert internal org-mode links to org-id links

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I have a document with a large number of internal text links. Some are formatted like this `[[Link to Heading]]` while others have descriptive text: `[[Link to Heading][description]]`.

I would like to change all such links in the current buffer to use `org-id` instead, i.e.,

```
[[#org-id-string][description]]
```